# Codeigniter Route Issues

Tags: codeigniter

Im wondering if someone could help me out.

Currently to view a users profile in my codeigniter app, the url is as follows:

```
http://www.website.com/profile/u/username
```

I would like to change this to read

```
http://www.website.com/username
```

Is this possible using routes? if so could someone give me a bit of advice how to do it?

Also, if someone signs up a username that is the same as a controller name, what would happen then?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1. Is this possible using routes?`

Yes.

`2. If so could someone give me a bit of advice how to do it?`

Sure: `$route['(:any)'] = "profile/u/$1";`

More info: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

`3. Also, if someone signs up a username that is the same as a controller name, what would happen then?`

You should not allow an user to sign up using a username like that. Facebook does this! (www.facebook.com/groups/123457890 = "groups" can't be used as username)

To avoid that an access to a controller is routed into a profile access, you should add a routing config **prior** to the one mentioned above, like this:

`$route['(admin|groups|signup)'] = "$1";`

Here we have a regular expression, easy to understand. You just need to separate your controller names with the vertical bar character.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for this ... just to verify, the last line prevents a user from signing http://www.website.com/groups etc etc ? .. Would it be more worthwhile having it as www.website.com/u/username just so there is no problems with controller names?

Comment: No, the last line does not prevent it. It only avoids that `www.website.com/groups` is routed to `www.website.com/profile/u/groups` (which is unwanted). The alternative you mentioned is easier. In a project where the client **wants** the www.website.com/username URL, then you must have a list of "reserved words" and forbid them to be used at signup. And you should also include them all to your regular expression route rule (which needs to come **first**). It's more work, but it's simple. Using `www.website.com/u/username` makes things easier and simple.

Comment: Beautiful, i think i might have the /u/ .... Sorry to be a pain, but how do i go about adding the /u/ to the route rule?

Comment: Thought I'd throw in, well put together answer, wish I could upvote more then once.

Answer (score 0):

this link could help you :
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/186025/

you can do as it said.

or

you must use apache rewrite module and use .htaccess first

RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
and delete index.php from applications/config/config.php
```

$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
and route with

```
$route['^(?=[^\s]*?[0-9])(?=[^\s]*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$'] = "user/$1";`
```